# Can't switch Firefox windows using command+tilde

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, firefox

I prefer using multiple Firefox windows. Until now I could easily switch between its different windows by using the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> shortcut. But all of a sudden I can't do that anymore.

I can still use the shortcut for other apps but not for Firefox. Both the windows are in the same space and I don't recall making any changes.

**Any hints on what's happened or how I can rectify this?**

Comment: Are all the windows in the same Space? It only works if they are.

Comment: I see the same problem, which hit suddenly after a Firefox restart (no version update). Strangely, _some_ Firefox windows switch normally, while others react on `cmd`+`~` by going back in tab's history.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I fixed the problem the following way.

I noticed that the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> stops at a specific window, while works on other Firefox windows.

I closed that window, then re-opened it via History menu. The effect was gone, and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> started working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that the system shortcut was modified.

You should go to:

`System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard`

**`Move focus to next window`** should be checked and contain the correct shortcut.

Comment: This probably happened because I changed input source changing, check your shortcuts if you ever messed around with those!